# What is the Meaning of the Following Code?

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
var reqArgs = {
            method :"POST",
            url: "reloadOrgCodes.action?tableName="+tableName+"&columnName="+columnName,
            load : function(type, data, evt) {
                dojo.byId('customerdiv').innerHTML = data;
            },
            mimetype :"text/plain"
        };
        dojo.io.bind(reqArgs);
        dojo.byId('customerdiv').innerHTML = "Loading....";

}
```

Comment: pls use 4 indents for letting the parser interpret your code as code, and indent all the code in a readable way

Comment: @perissf: please don't use "pls". I absolutely agree with you on all 4 items you suggest, but this is not a place for text-speak.

Answer (score 1):

The code sends a POST request to the server using XMLHttpRequest. The `load` function is called when the request is completed. `dojo.io.bind` is a quite old dojo function. So you're still using very old version of Dojo. Try to upgrade to new version.